# LCM in $\mathbb F_q[T]$

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

Let $q$ be a power of a prime $p$. We work in $\mathbb F_q[T]$. Put $L_n=\prod_{j=1}^n(T^{q^i}-T)$. Does one have
$$\deg(\mathrm{LCM}(L_{n+1};L^q_n))=\frac{q^{n+2}}{q-1}+o(q^n)$$
when $n\to\infty$?

Comment: You know that $T^{q^k}-T$ is the product of all the irreducible polynomials in $\Bbb{F}_q[T]$ of degree that is a factor of $k$, right? So if $f(T)$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $d$, it should be straightforward to calculate its multiplicity as a factor in both $L_{n+1}$ and $L_n^q$.

Comment: Sorry I changed the question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$h_n = \prod_{d|n} (T^{q^{n/d}}-T)^{\mu(d)} = \prod_{a\in \Bbb{F}_{q^n}, \Bbb{F}_q(a)=\Bbb{F}_{q^n}} (T-a)$$

They are coprime and
$$L_n = \prod_{j=1}^n h_j^{\lfloor n/j\rfloor}$$
Whence
$$lcm(L_{n+1},L_n^q)=L_n^q h_{n+1}$$
has degree $$q\sum_{j=1}^n q^j + \sum_{d|n+1} \mu(d) q^{(n+1)/d}$$